# The sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is $n(n+1)/2.$ How do we express this in Peano arithmetic?

Tags: logic

The following is a well-known proposition. $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} :\sum_{j=1}^n j = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

How do we actually express a sentence like this in the language of Peano Arithmetic?

Comment: What do you mean with *the language of Peano Arithmetic*? Do you mean just using the symbols $S, 0, +$ and $\cdot$, (and the logic symbols, of course)?

Comment: @GitGud, yeah that's what I meant. Other relation symbols are also acceptable, so long as its made clear what formula they're being used as a shorthand for.

Comment: So basically you're asking to define $\sum \limits _{j=1}^n$ and the fraction, right?

Comment: @GitGud, yeah. I already know how to do the fraction so I can probably fill that detail in myself. *Edit*. Indeed, it occurs to me that we can just take the $2$ to the LHS, so the division becomes a product.

Comment: You can define the sum recursively. If $n=0$, then it's just $0$. I suppose you can do the rest.

Comment: @GitGud, yes, but I'm not sure how translate the idea of 'defining something recursively' into an actual sentence of PA expressing that idea.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340111/recursion-schema-and-the-arithmetical-hierarchy

Comment: Why can't we just write $2(1+...+n)=n(n+1)$? Why do we need to invoke induction?

Comment: @Colin because $\ldots$ mean nothing, that's just a sort of device people use to summarize things.

Comment: @Colin: How do you prove that $2(1+\ldots+n)=n(n+1)$, for *every* $n$, without using induction?

Comment: Ah, I see. There is a universal quantifier at the beginning of the given statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $n \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^{n} j$ can be regarded as defining a certain primitive recursive function $f$:
\begin{align}
f (0) & = 0 \\
f (n + 1) & = f (n) + n + 1
\end{align}
Gödel has shown that every primitive recursive function is definable in Peano arithmetic. In our case, that means there exists a formula $\varphi (x, y)$ such that PA proves:

- $\varphi (x, y)$ is functional.
- $\varphi (0, 0)$.
- $\forall x . \varphi (x, y) \to \varphi (x+1, y + x + 1)$

The formula $\varphi$, even for such a simple function, is rather complicated. The hardest part is to develop a coding for finite lists of natural numbers. Once we have this, $\varphi (x, y)$ essentially says that there exists $L$ coding a finite list such that:

- The $0$-th entry of $L$ is $0$.
- If the $n$-th entry of $L$ is $a$, and $L$ has an $(n+1)$-th entry, then the $(n+1)$-th entry is $a + n + 1$.
- $L$ has an $x$-th entry.
- The $x$-th entry of $L$ is $y$.

The theorem you wish to state can then be formalised as follows:

$$\forall x. \exists y. \varphi (x, y) \land (2 \times y = x \times (x + 1))$$

Comment: For additional details of how the formula $\varphi$ is expressed, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/313049/462).

Answer (score 3):

You are interested in $f(n) = \sum_{j=0}^n j$. But evidently $f$ is primitive recursive, and there is a standard trick due to Gödel for expressing any primitive recursive function in the language of PA by deploying his so-called $\beta$-function [now outlined by Zhen Lin].

The clearest fuller explanation of that which I know is in P*t*r Sm*th's *Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*, Ch. 15 of the second edition (which is a bit too long to cut'n'paste here)!

Comment: Thanks, Ch15 has been enlightening. +1

Comment: Peter, what do you think of this? -- It occurs to me that, if instead of axiomatizing $\mathbb{N},$ if we instead axiomatized the hereditarily finite sets, then we wouldn't need a $\beta$ function. (Because a sequence of hereditarily finite sets can be described as a function in the usual way). Thoughts?